# Javascript style.display taking away <ul> bullets

Tags: javascript, html, css

After a little commenting out I've found that when I run this command in JavaScript the bullets in my unordered list disappear (each "page" is an item in my unordered list.):

```
pages[i].style.display = "block";
```

The padding of the `ul`, however, remains intact. How might I toggle with the `style.display` of a list item without removing the bullet?

Comment: A jsfiddle would be useful

Comment: _Any_ more detail would be useful. What is `pages[i]`? Is it a `<ul>` or an `<li>` or something else? It sounds like _ul_ because you say _"The padding of the ul"_, but a ul is normally `display:block` while an li is normally `display:list-item`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the [`display` to `list-item`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) instead, then (which is the default value for `li` elements).

In your case, it would be:

```
pages[i].style.display = 'list-item';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display: list-item` or `element.style.display = "list-item"` if you want to restore it to its previous look.

---

If you have only set the style in JavaScript like this:

```
element.style.display = 'none';
```

You can remove the inline style and reset it to its initial state by setting it to an empty string:

```
element.style.display = '';
```

This restores `display: list-item` for `<li>` elements, `display: inline` for `<span>` elements, `display: table` for `<table>` elements and so on.

Comment: This is more elegant in that it restores it to the original stylings instead of causing side effects and forcing previous state knowledge. :)